# How much can sub-optimal octane affect fuel economy?

Tags: fuel-consumption, gasoline, octane, efficiency

Pick any production car that is factory-tuned for high octane fuel.

We know that on lower-octane fuel it has to retard timing to avoid knocking.  In effect, it has to run at a lower compression ratio.  This is practically the definition of reduced fuel efficiency.

My question is: In practice, **how much can low-octane fuel affect fuel economy?**  E.g., if a car is tuned for 93 octane and is given 87 octane, how much worse can the mileage be?  1%?  10%?  If it's being run full-throttle/full-load on a track can it reach 50%?  I'm hoping for quantitative or authoritative references applicable to modern fuel-injected production vehicles.

Comment: Is there anything in this question that isn't part of the other question marked by Rory as a duplicate?

Comment: Oops ... I've obviously been thinking about this question for a while!